# com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character(code 160) while reading the json file

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

I am reading the below json content from a file and converting into a map but i am getting the below exception. Kindly let me know if anybody has come across such issue. I validated my json content and looks valid. Not sure why this error.

Json Content:

```
{
    "Results":[{         
        "TotalPositiveFeedbackCount": 0      
    },{
        "TotalPositiveFeedbackCount": 1      
    }   ]
}
```

Code:

```
Map<String, Object> domainMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
try {
    responseJson = getFile("reviewresponse.json");
    //responseJson = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("reviewresponse.json")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    ObjectMapper jsonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    jsonObjectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
    domainMap = jsonObjectMapper.readValue(responseJson,
                   new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
}
```

Exception Details:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (' ' (code 160)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name
 at [Source: {
    "Results":[{         
        "TotalPositiveFeedbackCount": 0      
    },{
        "TotalPositiveFeedbackCount": 1      
    }   ]
}
; line: 2, column: 15]
```

Comment: Your input probably contains an invisible character on line 2, column 15. What happens if you try reading another input file that you've typed in by hand?

Comment: Character code 160 is a non-breaking space which according to [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) is not valid JSON whitespace.

Comment: Thanks !! It worked after typing the content. I believe some space was there while copy pasting

Comment: This can happen if you send a HTTP request as application/txt instead of application/json

Answer (score 13):

Your JSON content contains non-breaking spaces (character code 160, commonly known as `&nbsp;`) likely from copying and pasting JSON (usually from a webpage) that used `&nbsp;` to indent the JSON.

[image]

You can fix it with

```
responseJson = responseJson.replace('\u00A0',' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

had same issue with body sent via postman
Just copy pasted the text into sublime text editor which shown as below, The picture shows some extra formatting in space which is not a valid json white space
[image]

After removing them and just spacing properly in sublime worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Google for Json formatter then click on any one of the option ,
Paste your json code in that formatter , it will validate & highlight the unwanted characters just delete them or replace then with what you want.

e.g. goto https://jsonformatter.org/
& follow the above steps