# How to send a POST request with Kotlin/Native using libcurl?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, libcurl, kotlin-native

I'm trying to send a JSON through a POST request with a Kotlin/Native application using libcurl. I'm working on a Windows 11 machine, and the endpoint lies under a Spring Boot (version 2.7.8) backend written with Kotlin and Java 11.
The following is the code I wrote to accomplish this task.

```
import kotlinx.cinterop.*
import libcurl.*

fun main() {
    val curl = curl_easy_init()
    curl?.let {
        var headers: CValuesRef<curl_slist>? = null

        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json")
        setCurl(curl, headers)

        val res = curl_easy_perform(curl)
        if (res != CURLE_OK) println("curl_easy_perform() failed ${curl_easy_strerror(res)?.toKString()}")
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl)
        curl_slist_free_all(headers)

    } ?: println("curl_easy_init() failed to return curl easy handle")
}

private fun setCurl(curl: COpaquePointer?, headers: CPointer<curl_slist>?) {
    val body = "{ JSON object }"
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers)
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, body)
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/dishes/add/")
}
```

The JSON string I need to send represents a simple `Dish` object having three fields: `name`, `type` and `description`.

These are the attempts I made to correctly format the JSON string to initialize the `val body` and the relative outputs that the Spring Boot endpoint return:

1. `{\"name\":\"Fish\",\"type\":\"Second\",\"description\":\"Fry\"}` => `HTTP 200`;
2. `{\"name\":\"Fish fry\",\"type\":\"Second course\",\"description\":\"Lots of fresh fish to delight the palate with an excellent, fried second course\"}` => `HTTP 400: JSON parse error: Unexpected character (' ' (code 160)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')`;
3. `{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Fish fry\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"Second course\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"Lots of fresh fish to delight the palate with an excellent, fried second course\\\"}` => `HTTP 400: JSON parse error: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 0)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens`;
4. `"\"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Fish fry\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"Second course\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"Lots of fresh fish to delight the palate with an excellent, fried second course\\\"}\""` => `HTTP 400: JSON parse error: Unexpected character (' ' (code 160)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')`

From the above tests, I can effectively POST something on the backend only with the first `body` string, but if I try to send a longer one with even the same format (see the second one), the POST request fails too.

Besides, I also tried to execute a POST request using Postman and the terminal (with the following command: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"name\":\"Fish fry\",\"type\":\"Second course\",\"description\":\"Lots of fresh fish to delight the palate with an excellent, fried second course\"}" http://localhost:8080/dishes/add/`), and with both, I can correctly send the POSTs. And since using the commands prompt, curl accepts the last `body` JSON I tried, maybe it could be the right approach to format the string, but I'm not sure.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your precious time!

**UPDATE 1:**

I just discovered the `--libcurl` curl parameter, which lets you convert a curl command into libcurl code.
Using this helpful tool, I converted my working cmd POST request

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"name\":\"Fish fry\",\"type\":\"Second course\",\"description\":\"Lots of fresh fish to delight the palate with an excellent, fried second course\"}" http://localhost:8080/dishes/add/
```

Into the following, Kotlin adapted, C snippet:

```
private fun setCurl(hnd: COpaquePointer?, certPath: String, url: String) {
    var headers: CValuesRef<curl_slist>? = null

    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json")

    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 102400L)
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/dishes/add/")
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L)
    curl_easy_setopt(
        hnd,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "{\"name\":\"Fish fry\",\"type\":\"Second course\",\"description\":\"Lots of fresh fish to delight the palate with an excellent, fried second course\"}"
    )
    val postFieldSize: curl_off_t = 138
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, postFieldSize)
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers)
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.83.1")
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50L)
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST")
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP, 1L)
    curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L)
}
```

But still, my Kotlin/Native application failed to execute the request with Spring Boot returning the same error: `Unexpected character (' ' (code 160)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')`.

At this time, I ran out of ideas. Please, let me know about any other solutions.

**UPDATE 2:**

Since the first `val body` initialization was the only one to be successful (despite the `body` string having to be small), I started to do some other tests with that type of formatted JSON, so I found that the POST request is successful **if the entire string does not cross the 63 chars of length** otherwise, the Spring Boot endpoint fires the error regarding the code 160 unexpected character.
The body string I'm currently using is the following one, which length is exactly 63 chars.

```
{\"name\":\"Fettuccine Alfredo\",\"type\":\"Main co\",\"description\":\"\"}
```

I don't know why this situation is happening, and I'm very frustrated.
Every tip of advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047214/com-fasterxml-jackson-core-jsonparseexception-unexpected-charactercode-160-wh

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already tried that solution before posting this question, and it did not solve my problem.
I reviewed many questions regarding this issue but didn't find a solution.